# Disable detecting/linking of URL's

Tags: mpdf

Is there a way to disable the detection of URL's in Mpdf 6.1? My main problem is that Mpdf disables automatic line-breaking inside "detected" URL's.
https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/line-breaking.html

Thanks, Hannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mpdf 6.1. this is not possible, but I created a [PR](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/388) which will hopefully get merged.